# Terraform vs Airflow for creating a spark cluster on Google Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, terraform-provider-gcp

A google dataproc cluster can be created by the airflow using Google Cloud Dataproc Operators. The same can be achieved using Terraform modules as well. When should I got for airflow and when it should be terraform

Comment: Do you actually know what terraform is? Airflow vs. terraform is not really a comparison that makes sense.

Comment: I understand these cant be directly compared. What's the best way to orchestrate ephemeral cluster creation when it can be achieved in multiple ways